# Integration to Chainlink from other blockchains

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, chainlink

I've seen one way on how to integrate chainlink with other blockchains, json-rpc for example. Is there some documentation on this topic? And in general are these done by adapters, node.js for example with JS clients for both chains (worker node and publisher)? Any hint greatly appreciated.

E.g. what are the general requiremennts for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To integrate Chainlink with another blockchain, you need 3 pieces:

1. A way to read events from the new blockchain
2. A way to send transactions from the node to the new blockchain
3. A LINK token bridge

#1 is defined by [external initiators](https://docs.chain.link/docs/external-initiators-introduction). These are just processes that learn how to read the new blockchains

#2 is defined by [external adapters](https://docs.chain.link/docs/external-adapters). These are just processes that can write back to the chains (and do anything else really)

#3 There isn't a standard token bridge for all blockchains, but one could actually build a token bridge out of Chainlink's proof of reserve.

A good example of a blockchain integration with a very different blockchain is [Chainlink with Conflux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZLeEi3izkTY). You can see the example code in their repos.